# Unable to load webview in desktop on messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I created a facebook messenger bot. But the problem is I was unable to load Webview on the desktop but it works on messenger app in android.
I have already whitelisted the url which i wanted to load.
I looked at the console and saw the error in the screen at the console.

[image]
The iframe was unable to load because it set the iframe options to deny.
After i read the documentation.

So i need to confirm, is it definitely not able to work on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to load it on desktop. You just need to correctly set the X-Frame-Options header in your server/application.

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/
```

Here is the [Facebook documentation about this subject](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#iframe).